# How can you copy html element and style,on document ready

Tags: jquery, html

Hello folks i want to make a table from divs in my website,and i need to copy the parent div and his childs multiple times.I am trying from like 2 days already and i cannot find the perfect combo to do it,here is what i have done.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
       var obj = $(".food-content");
     for (var i=0;i<12;i++){
        $(obj).appendd(obj.clone(true));
    }
});
```

Here is link to the codepen:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mOjzVM

I need a copy of "food-content" like 12 times and need to append it to the same element on document ready.Can somebody please finish this code ;?

Comment: what exactly you are looking for ...you did not add jQuery to the codepen

Comment: It is there for me..
I want instead of spamming 12 times the html code in my page.php (because it will be like new 50 rows of code) to make 12 copies of parent element.In case with codepen i want to copy ".food-content" and its styling 12 times on document ready.

Comment: is this what you want http://codepen.io/sahithiK/pen/VmBOvm

Comment: Thats exactly what i was looking for,Thanks!! How is it possible mate,lol our codes are exactly the same and your works,mine don't...
PS:I saw that i was miss spelled append with 1 more d.

Comment: @Geeky your solution doesn't seem to work as intended. If you look at the element structure of the results, instead of 12 copies of `food-content`, you actually have tens of thousands of `food-content` divs recursively existing inside each other. This is because you are appending to `obj` and therefore A) you are appending inside the obj and B) every time a new one is appended, further iterations also append inside the new ones.

Comment: Yaa right ..@DaemonOfTheWest seems to be right

Comment: thanks both of ya guys,i am trying for 2 days like 8 hours total to write 2 lines of code for copy the div,lol.I am like Never surrender,no matter how stupid you are ;D

Comment: @Dako There's a difference between being stupid and just not knowing yet :) you're not stupid, you're just learning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issues with your code:

1. You already defined `obj` as `$(".food-content")` and therefore it is a jQuery reference to an HTML object. Calling `$(obj)` returns an error because `$()` requires a string as input, not a reference. You should use `obj` instead.
2. `append()` is misspelled. Furthermore, you are using the function incorrectly. If you wish to clone an element, you must append to its **parent**, not itself. Otherwise you get multiple `obj` elements inside each other, which is not what you want.

The corrected code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var obj = $(".food-content");
  for (var i=0; i<12; i++){
    $('body').append(obj.clone());
  }
});
```

Note that `body` should be replaced with the parent element if you have one.

Furthermore, your CodePen doesn't have the JQuery library enabled. You should fix that if you wish to test the code in CodePen.

Comment: I'am pretty newbish at those things,thanks for all the tips mate,it will help me a lot in future.